# How many clock cycles does reading digital input on an AVR microcontrollers take?

Tags: avr

How many clock cycles does it take to read digital inputs in avr microcontrollers? For example, how many clock cycles would SomePreDeclaredByte = PINB; take?

Comment: Have you looked at a data sheet?

Comment: Have you looked at the Assembly code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading from a `PINx` in the basic 64 I/O registers takes 1 cycle. Reading from outside of that takes between 1 and 3 cycles depending on the specific architecture, with 2 cycles being the most common. Note that this does not include the cycles taken up by the synchronizer reading the external value; see the device datasheet for more information about this.